# Customizing an UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I would want to create a custom `UITableViewCell` which should have a different appearance than the default implementation. For this I subclassed the `UITableViewCell` and want to add a label, textbox and a background image. Only the background image seems not to appear.
Maybe I'm completely on the wrong track here and maybe subclassing a `UITableViewCell` is a bad idea after all, is there any reason why that would be the case and is there a better way?

Anyhow this is what I tried, in the subclass's `initWithStyle` I put the following:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier 
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self == nil)
    { 
        return nil;
    }

     UIImage *rowBackground;

     backRowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backRow.png"];
     ((UIImageView *)self.backgroundView).image = backRowImage;

 }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Should I set the background image in the `drawRect` method as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the header file, the backgroundView defaults to nil for plain-style tables. You should try creating your own UIImageView and sticking it in there.

Answer (score 4):

When I subclass `UITableViewCell`, I override the `layoutSubviews` method, and use CGRects to place my subViews inside the `contentView` of the cell, like so:

First, in your `initWithFrame` method:

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        //bgImageView is declared in the header as UIImageView *bgHeader;
        bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        bgImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourFileName.png"];

        //add the subView to the cell
        [self.contentView addSubview:bgImageView];
        //be sure to release bgImageView in the dealloc method!
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then you Override `layoutSubviews`, like so:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect imageRectangle = CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,320.0f,44.0f); //cells are 44 px high
    bgImageView.frame = imageRectangle;
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that using `initWithStyle`, depending on the style you use, will sometimes prevent you from modifying certain properties of the default `UILabel` in the cell such as the frame or text alignment. You might want to simply override a different init method for the cell and then manually add new `UILabel`. This is what I do for any drastically customized `UITableViewCell` subclasses.