# Showing more information in custom table cell of iPhone

Tags: iphone

I implemented table view in my app. Now in a table cell right now I am showing only three items, which I feel are very less. What I want to show is that first is an image then another image then text and then accessory. So how can I accomplish this????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass UITableViewCell and then customize it to your demands. You can listen to events or add any Subviews you want. This topic covers your needs I think:

[Customizing an UITableViewCell subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366802/customizing-an-uitableviewcell-subclass)