# Audio player using UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, audio, uitableview

I would like to create an audio player using UITableView. Every song needs to be a row in this table view controller and I expect every cell to have a play/stop button (only two states). I am managing all the audio meta-data using Core Data and actually storing the song files inside the sandbox (this is a demo application). Which is the best way to go about it? How can I have dynamic content inside UITableViewCells?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: I know its quite older question but I am facing the same problem right now. I just want to know how did you overcome this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Subclass UITableViewCell to create two buttons inside of your cells.
2. Assign them actions in the controller for the tableView, and check the indexPath (or a custom identifier assigned to the cell, but that wouldn't be very mvc aware...) of the cells that were toggled to know what sound to play.

   - Be careful with how the cells are reused to know what state to display.

Comment: Uh... how do I subclass UITableViewCell? Can I have a pseudocode-type example please?

Comment: Try this http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366802/customizing-an-uitableviewcell-subclass

Basically, you subclass like you'd subclass anything in objective-c, then override the UIView methods to insert your subviews.  You can also do all that in NIB, I suppose Google can help you very easily in finding a tutorial!

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know!

Comment: Hey Remy, thanks for the lead. I just started working on this and I have a question: As I said, previously, my expected functionality is to have a play/stop button beside the name of the song. Can I, instead of subclassing, just add UIButton subviews (for the play/stop buttons)? Are there any potential disadvantages that I am overlooking if I choose this method?